# Por que o header User-Agent retorna sempre "Mozilla /5.0" independente do navegador?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, user-agent

Sei que no PHP podemos acessar um `header` chamado `User-Agent` e, assim, descobrir informações sobre o sistema operacional e navegador, utilizado pelo cliente.

A única coisa que não entendo é que sempre aparece "Mozilla /5.0" (mesmo que eu utilize outro navegador, que não o Firefox).

Exemplo:

```
print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Saída:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
```

Essa string acima foi retornada do PHP. Estava utilizando `Firefox 39.0`nos meus testes. Porém, se eu fizesse isso com outro navegador, me retornaria o "Mozilla/5.0"

Então aqui vão duas perguntas (estarei satisfeito se apenas a primeira for respondida):

- Por que é que esse header retorna o nome do navegador, também retorna "Mozilla /5.0"? É outra coisa que não tem relacionamento nenhum com Firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu não sei responder em detalhes. Estou respondendo apenas para ter uma resposta que não é errada.

O motivo dos navegadores usarem isto deve ser mais ou menos o mesmo motivo do que alegam o [Windows 10 não chamar Windows 9](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/windows-10/63877-novo-sistema-microsoft-chama-windows-10-rumor.htm).

Programadores ruins ou preguiçosos ou maliciosos usam a *string* `Mozilla` para fazer certas verificações em seus códigos e saber se pode executar alguma coisa. Se usasse o próprio nome, um monte de código existente que poderia rodar normalmente não funcionaria por um `if` mal colocado.

Então todos navegadores [fingem serem o Mozilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing) para não serem prejudicados por códigos ruins.

Na verdade a coisa é pior porque eles gostam de por várias palavras para se passar por vários navegadores.

Comment: Aqui no setor de TI temos um bordão para isso: _Nossa, que gambiarra!_

Comment: Provavelmente, alguma coisa bem na linha dos programadores _"ruins ou preguiçosos ..."_ e do _"... if mal colocado"_ faz com que o widget de fotos do Estadão não funcione no Opera :)

Answer (score 5):

Esse excelente [artigo sobre a história dos navegadores](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) explica um pouco sobre a história deles, e o trecho abaixo é o que mais interessa para o contexto da pergunta:

> (...) Mozilla built Gecko, and called itself Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.1) Gecko/20020826, and Gecko was the rendering engine, and Gecko was good. And Mozilla became Firefox, and called itself Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; sv-SE; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041108 Firefox/1.0, and Firefox was very good.
>
> And Gecko began to multiply, and other browsers were born that used its code, and they called themselves Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X Mach-O; en-US; rv:1.7.2) Gecko/20040825 Camino/0.8.1 the one, and Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.8.1.8) Gecko/20071008 SeaMonkey/1.0 another, each pretending to be Mozilla, and all of them powered by Gecko.

Basicamente, o Gecko (que também se chama Mozilla/5.0) é o motor de renderização open-source implementado pela maioria dos navegadores hoje em dia — por isso que a *string* de user-agent começa com Mozilla/5.0.

Comment: Esta resposta está errada. O IE não usa o Gecko e tem esta *string* como *user-agent*. O mesmo vale para o Chrome, Opera e o Safari, só para ficar nos principais mesmo.

Comment: Então por que é que aparece isso @bigown?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters está na minha resposta

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro é preciso entender o significado *user-agent*, ou o agente do usuário, ou seja o que age/interage.

Em geral, é necessário saber qual tipo de funcionalidade é compatível com esse agente, para então disponibilizar o conteúdo em uma maneira interpretável para o mesmo, e é daí que a confusão com a repetida *Mozilla* começa.

O primeiro [navegador web](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navegador_web), lançado em 1993, foi o [Mosaic](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic), e este utilizava *user-agent*: `NCSA_Mosaic/2.0`.

A *Mosaic Communications*, responsável pelo navegador, tornou-se [Netscape Communications](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Communications_Corporation), e criou o [Netscape Navigator](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator), que inicialmente se chamava *Mozilla* (uma brincadeira na junção em inglês de *Mosaic* e *Killer* - Matador do Mosaic), e portanto sua *user-agent* era `Mozilla/1.0`.

Como o navegador da *Netscape* inseria interpretações para novas funcionalidades, como *frames*, os [servidores web](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_web) passaram a prover páginas com os novos recursos, mas precisavam manter compatibilidade com o antigo *Mosaic*, então, restringiam as novas páginas aos agentes que continham *Mozilla*, enviando a página antiga, compatível com o *Mosaic*, aos que não tinham.

Quando a [Microsoft](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft) criou o [Internet Explorer](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_explorer), lançado em 1995, este tinha suporte a *frames* e demais funcionalidades do *Netscape*, mas seu *user-agent* não continha *Mozilla*, o que fazia com que os servidores retornassem o conteúdo pobre, interpretando-o como *Mosaic*. <sup>[8](https://www.howtogeek.com/114937/htg-explains-whats-a-browser-user-agent/)</sup>

Impaciente por esperar que os [administradores](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmaster) tomassem consciência de seu novo navegador, este se apropriou do nome, e passou a enviar a *user-agent* `Mozilla/1.22`, declarando-se compatível com o agente *Mozilla*. <sup>[10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Format_for_human-operated_web_browsers)</sup>

Assim, **o agente do usuário tem a função de especificar compatibilidades**, e é utilizado assim até hoje, dizendo que ele compatível ao *Mozilla*, ou com `KHTML like Gecko` para mostrar suporte às funcionalidades do [Gecko](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(motor_de_layout)), e navegadores [Android](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android) se passando por [Safari](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari). <sup>[14](https://web.archive.org/web/20110806170335/http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f8/android-browser-reports-itself-as-apple-safari-4701/)</sup> <sup>[15](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox)</sup>

Note que este **não tem relação com a organização sem fins lucrativos [Mozilla](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Foundation), responsável pelo [Firefox](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox)**.